# OCaml Syntax Error while using Threads

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

```
let set n v = Thread.delay 1.0; (n := v) in 

let result1 x = set x (!x + 1) in

let result2 x = set x (!x * !x) in

let run i = 

let original = 2 in

  let r = ref (original) in 

  let t1 = Thread.create result1 r; let v1 = !r in

  let v2 = !(result2 r) ;

  Thread.join t1 ;

  Printf.printf "number is %n" (v1 + v2) in 

let main() =
     run 1;
     run 2 in 

  main() ;;
```

In the above program, I am using threads but could not figure out where the syntax error is. If anyone could help me to figure out what the error is.

Comment: Code lines should be formatted as such, with at least four spaces in front of each of them (and an empty line before and after the code block). So edit your question to improve the formatting, and show *exactly* the error message you get

Comment: Error is just "Syntax Error" in the last line.

Comment: Your code is very confusing because of your heavy use of `let .. in` and the sequence operator, and the obtuse variable names. You might want to use ocp-indent, which will indent the code and to some extent reveal how it's interpreted which might reveal the bug. You might also want to split it up into several small functions since it will give the code more structure and boundaries that both make it easier to read and easier to discover bugs.

Comment: You can try out ocp-indent by pasting your code here: https://try.ocamlpro.com/fun-demo/tryocaml_index.html

Answer (score 0):

This line:

let t1 = Thread.create result1 r; let v1 = !r in

Has two `let`s but only one `in`. I think you need another `in` here.

As a side comment, this is an unidiomatic way to structure your code at the top level of a file. It would be more usual to have a series of top-level definitions, which use `let` but not `in`. So it would look something like this:

```
let set n v = Thread.delay 1.0; (n := v)
let result1 x = set x (!x + 1)
let result2 x = set x (!x * !x)

let run i =
    let original = 2 in
    let r = ref (original) in
    let t1 = Thread.create result1 r in
    let v1 = !r in
    let v2 = !(result2 r) in
    Thread.join t1;
    Printf.printf "number is %n" (v1 + v2)

let main () = run 1; run 2

let () = main ()
```

(I haven't compiled this so there might be a few syntax errors, apologies in advance. Just trying to show the basic layout.)